# How To Send Google Login Info From Firebase Database To Navigation Drawer?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have a login activity where users can log into their Google account through firebase, It works perfectly but the problem I'm having is sending that info to the navigation drawer. I tried almost every code about this issue here on StackOverflow but nothing seems to work with my code, Can someone please help me with this I greatly appreciate it.

This is what I tried so far:

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private DrawerLayout drawer;
TextView text;
ImageView image;
FirebaseAuth mAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    text = findViewById(R.id.nav_text);
    image = findViewById(R.id.nav_image);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        updateUI(user);
    }



    drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    TextView text = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.nav_text);


    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();



}




private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
    if (user != null) {
        String name = user.getDisplayName();
        String email = user.getEmail();
        String photo = String.valueOf(user.getPhotoUrl());

        text.append(name + "\n");
        text.append(email);
        Picasso.get().load(photo).into(image);
    } else {
        Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.ic_firebase_logo).into(image);
    }
}
```

nav_header.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="176dp"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="16dp"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/nav_image"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_firebase_logo"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nav_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/user_1234"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nav_mail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/info_user1234_com" />
```

LoginActivity

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

static final int GOOGLE_SIGN_IN = 123;
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
Button btn_login, btn_logout;
TextView text;
ImageView image;
ProgressBar progressBar;
GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    btn_login = findViewById(R.id.login);
    btn_logout = findViewById(R.id.logout);
    text = findViewById(R.id.text);
    image = findViewById(R.id.image);
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_circular);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

    btn_login.setOnClickListener(v -> SignInGoogle());
    btn_logout.setOnClickListener(v -> Logout());

    if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        updateUI(user);
    }
}

public void SignInGoogle() {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, GOOGLE_SIGN_IN);
}

private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    Log.d("TAG", "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    Log.d("TAG", "signInWithCredential:success");

                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    updateUI(user);
                } else {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    Log.w("TAG", "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());

                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    updateUI(null);
                }
            });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == GOOGLE_SIGN_IN) {
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        try {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
            if (account != null) firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            Log.w("TAG", "Google sign in failed", e);
        }
    }
}

private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
    if (user != null) {
        String name = user.getDisplayName();
        String email = user.getEmail();
        String photo = String.valueOf(user.getPhotoUrl());

        text.append("Info : \n");
        text.append(name + "\n");
        text.append(email);
        Picasso.get().load(photo).into(image);
        btn_logout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btn_login.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        text.setText("Firebase Login \n");
        Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.ic_firebase_logo).into(image);
        btn_logout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        btn_login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

private void Logout() {
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
    mGoogleSignInClient.signOut().addOnCompleteListener(this,
            task -> updateUI(null));
}
```

activity_login.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
tools:context="com.sciyoutec.sci_youtec.LoginActivity">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_firebase_logo"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/image"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/google_login"
    android:textColor="@color/action"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<ProgressBar
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:id="@+id/progress_circular"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/text"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
    android:text="@string/login_with_google"
    android:background="@drawable/round_bg"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_google_logo"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_google_logo"/>

<Button
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:id="@+id/logout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
    android:text="@string/logout"
    android:background="@drawable/round_bg"/>
```

Logcat crash report

05-19 10:36:09.734 5132-22581/? E/PairHttpConnection: S3 request >16K, might fail (size=16868) http://b/15866117

Comment: I think this [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseApp-Clean-Architecture-MVVM) might help.

Comment: Ok I look into it and report back if it helps me or not

Comment: Your code seems to be useful be it's overwhelming for me. I'm new to android so I might not understand some things. If you can look at my code and guide me on how to implement your code to solve my problem that will be most helpful.

Comment: I was able to solve my problem thanks to the answer by VSS CHAITANYA Chavali. But thanks for your help. The part of your code I understand is how to create a profile activity for users, so your code is very useful.

Comment: Good to hear that Brad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue. Did this.

```
NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
View headerLayout = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    .
    .
    .
text = headerLayout.findViewById(R.id.nav_text);
image = headerLayout.findViewById(R.id.nav_image);
```

I don't know if you have tried this, but it worked for me.

Comment: This didn't work for me my app crashes after I log in my google account. The error message is: 05-15 14:59:00.706 10600-31432/? E/PairHttpConnection: S3 request >16K, might fail (size=16693) http://b/15866117. I don't know what that error means.
But thanks for the reply.

Comment: Try to debug and check at what statement the app crashes. Also post the logcat in the question, that would be helpful.

Comment: @BradTEC What exactly is happening? Is the app crashing?

Comment: Let me explain, When I log into my google account it works fine but still nothing shows in the navigation drawer so I thought I might have to reload the app, So I did that. But when I close the app and try to load it back up it crashes.

Comment: Post the logcat when the app crashes. It appears in red colour. Also post the text. Not image.

Comment: I've updated my question with the logcat that's in red, It's the only thing it telling me when I open the app

Comment: Set a breakpoint at the first statement of the onCreate of login activity and step through it. Find out at which statement exactly, it is crashing.

Comment: Thanks for your continuous help, Your code actually works, it was my coding that was the error. I did what you told me about the breakpoint and I found out that I had to move the getCurrentUser method to the bottom of the oncreate method in the main activity.

Comment: Glad to hear that.